# Horizontal viewport was given unbounded width with Text widget and Marquee flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, marquee

I am trying to build listview and inside it I have Title text for youtube and that text is long for which i am trying to use Marquee. But it keeps giving me below error, I tried adding shrinkwrap but it didn't solve the issue. Also i noticed many people reporting similar issue with height, but solution provided in those didn't help me..

[image]
[image]

```
child: ListView.builder(
       itemCount: ytResult.length,
       shrinkWrap: true,
       itemBuilder: (_, int index) => listsongs(index),                
),
```

---------------------------------listSong widget------------------------

```
Widget listsongs(index){
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(ytResult[index].thumbnail['high']['url']),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
          ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10),
            child: Row(              
              children: <Widget> [

                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  
                  child: Column(
                    
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Marquee(
                        text: ytResult[index].title,                        
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize:18.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                        
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ]
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Why do you have both `Row` and `Column` widgets with only 1 child? The issue likely is with the `Row`.

Comment: i have 2 rows actually, but i was trying to minimize issue by removing second row as Error is around first row.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Marquee widget as below in a container and set width and height. It solved my issue.

```
Expanded(child : Container(child : Marquee(  height:30,width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,text : "Hello Rajesh")))
```

Answer (score 0):

testing I realized that what in my case really solved the problem was wrapping it in an Expanded() widget, and Container() was not necessary...

```
Expanded(
      child: Marquee(
        text: 'GeeksforGeeks.org was created'
            ' of technology lovers and computer science enthusiasts'
            ' have been constantly working in this direction ',
      ),
    );
```